# Javascript Highcharts High buttons and calender with jquery

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highchart / Javascript and I am looking for a way to hide the buttons and calender (see image below[image]) with css or jquery.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you give us some more info with a https://jsfiddle.net/ or similar

Comment: Highcharts documentation is pretty clear. What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: It's basically want to force hiding the parts using jquery / css and that's not in the highcharts docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts do not have date range selector, Highstocks do.

See documentation for [rangeSelector](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector), in particular `rangeSelector.enabled`.